# How do I properly access uid from firebase to add a record into another database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a record to a realtime database in firebase. I run uer authentication and after that want to insert another data record, passing the uid to the new user in the other database. Below is a piece of the call:

```
    state = { email: '', password: '', errorMessage: null, uid: null }


    handleSignUp = () => {
      firebase.auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
          .then((user)=>{
            //console.log('uid',user.user.uid)
            this.setState({ uid: user.user.uid })
          })
          .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))
          .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))

          //insert new record into our realtime database
          this.addUser(this.state.uid,this.state.email,1000); //users are given 1000 in rewards to start

      }


// when a user signs up they will have a record added to the user table in realtime database
      addUser = (id,email,rewards) => {
        console.log(id)
        Firebase.database().ref('UsersList/').push({
          id,
          email,
          rewards
      }).then((data)=>{
          //success callback
          console.log('data ' , data)
      }).catch((error)=>{
          //error callback
          console.log('error ' , error)
      })
      }
```

It runs and adds a user but the uid comes out null. Email and name come from text inputs in forms. 
`this.state.uid` is showing `null` which I figure is because I haven't dealt with this in an asynchronous fashion. How would I go about repairing this so that it will run?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want instead?

```
this.addUser(user.user.uid, this.state.email, 1000);
```

I believe `setState` does not take effect immediately - it's going to do its work asynchronously.  If you want to pass along that uid, just pass the known value directly.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to `setState` are executed asynchronously, so by the time you call `this.addUser(...)` the `this.state.uid` hasn't been updated yet.

Doug's solution will work, but as an alternative you can put the call to `thisaddUser9...)` into the `then` handler that you already have for the `setState` call, since that runs after `setState` has completed.

So something like:

```
handleSignUp = () => {
  firebase.auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((user)=>{
        //console.log('uid',user.user.uid)
        this.setState({ uid: user.user.uid })
      })
      .then(() => {
        //insert new record into our realtime database
        this.addUser(this.state.uid,this.state.email,1000); //users are given 1000 in rewards to start

        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))

  }
```

---

Since the call to Firebase actually also runs asynchronously, you may want to consider chaining the promise that returns into your current chain.

```
handleSignUp = () => {
  firebase.auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user)=>{
        //console.log('uid',user.user.uid)
        this.setState({ uid: user.user.uid })
      }).then(() => {
        //insert new record into our realtime database
        return this.addUser(this.state.uid,this.state.email,1000); //users are given 1000 in rewards to start
      }).then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
      }).catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))
  }


  addUser = (id,email,rewards) => {
    return Firebase.database().ref('UsersList/').push({
      id,
      email,
      rewards
    });
  }
```